# kohana 3.0 directory to controller

Tags: php, kohana, routes

I have my website under Kohana 3.0 which works perfectly with the defaut Route

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
     ->defaults(array(
          'controller' => 'user',
      'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

When I try to access my website at this address `http://127.0.0.1/web/` It loads the url `http://127.0.0.1/web/user` . It is OK.
But now I want to add the admin directory under the controller. So my web tree looks like this

```
classes
|  controller/
       Admin/
          dashboard
       web.php
|  model
```

I would like to allow the Admin to access the admin's page in a url like this
`http://127.0.0.1/admin/dashboard`. Where dashboard is the controller under the admin's directory.
I modify the bootstrap file with this

```
Route::set('admin', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
        array('directory' => '(admin)'))->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

I can access the admin session through `http://127.0.0.1/web/admin/dashboard/`
But I can't access the default controller that is `http://127.0.0.1/web/` . The error `Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI:` 
I am missing the default access for the controller.
How can I set Route it to make access to my web site either through the link:

```
http://127.0.0.1/web/
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1/web/admin/dashboard/
```

**EDIT**
From the kohana documentation, it is written

```
In this example, we have controllers in two directories, admin and affiliate. Because this route will only match urls that begin with admin or affiliate, the default route would still work for controllers in classes/controller.
Route::set('sections', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
    array(
        'directory' => '(admin|affiliate)'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Source : `http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#examples`

Now I modify my code to

```
Route::set('default', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
        array(
            'directory' => '(admin)'))
        ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

but I have this error

```
Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI:
```

when I want to access the default controller like `http://127.0.0.1/user/index`

Comment: the "web" folder doesn't exists. It would have to be `http://127.0.0.1/admin/web`. with that router, your directory isn't optional

Comment: I make a mistake it is http://127.0.0.1/user/index

Comment: edit your answer with the right code then, because I don't know you are talking about user or admin

Comment: it's recomended that you use multiple routes instead of trying to solve your problem with a generic catch-all route.

Comment: Yes it works with multiple routes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route would translate to: `http://127.0.0.1/admin/web`, but your `Admin` folder would need to have `user` controller inside.

```
Route::set('default', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
    array(
        'directory' => '(admin)'))
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

If you want the directory to be optional, you'd need to

```
Route::set('default', '(<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))',
    array(
        'directory' => '(admin)'
    )
)
    ->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'admin', 
    'controller' => 'dashboard',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

But, in your case, you need multiple routes. Above the "catch all" route, put this:

```
Route::set('user', 'user(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'user',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'dashboard',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Comment: with the default Route Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
     ->defaults(array(
          'controller' => 'user',
      'action'     => 'index',
    )); Everything works well. Now I want to add the Admin directory so that when the admin types http://127.0.0.1/admin/dashboard/login , he is directed to the controller inside the admin folder and if a simple User , he can access directly through the default that http://127.0.0.1/user/login . The files for User is in classes/controller/ not a subdirectory

Comment: oh good @pocesar multiple routes, this seems to solve my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the directory inside `->defaults`

```
Route::set('whatever', 'whatever')
    ->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

Comment: No @JGSilve, by inserting directory to ->defaults it does not work. In fact by doing so it tells Kohana that the User.php is under admin directory. This is not the case. As I drew up , under Controller folder there are admin folder (which contains Dashboard.php) and User.php